# How can I equip stuff?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I bought some clothing from the stash, but I cannot equip even one of them.  My old clothing is always equipped and I can't remove them either. Can anyone help?

Comment: I've got the same problem when i press the equip button the green check mark does not appear

Answer (score 5):

In THE STASH,

[image: THE STASH]

Go to the section with the item you wish to equip (CLOTHING in your case):

[image: CLOTHING]

Select/tap on the item that you wish to equip and it will expand down to show a button. If you have not purchased the item, the button will say, <kbd>BUY</kbd> (see above) and in that case you must first purchase the item with in-game coins. If you have purchased the item, the button will say, <kbd>EQUIP</kbd>.

Tap the <kbd>EQUIP</kbd> button to equip the selected/expanded item. You will see a green check mark on the currently equipped items.

Items available for purchase will be at the top of the list under a Green **∇ FOR SALE ∇** section and will each list a price in coins. Items you have purchased in a previous visit to that page of THE STASH will be in the section below with the blue heading **∇ MY ITEMS ∇** and will not list any prices, but will have a colored light to their left.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING AT ME

Comment: @Mana Shouting? I used the same case as in the UI which I was describing. Are you sure it wasn't...the voices?

Comment: I was making a poor joke about the UI's case. :(